# How do I convert a JSON file into a JS array

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to convert a word list stored in a JSON file into an array in my code. This is my code so far:

```
     var jstring;

    $.getJSON( "link_to_json.json", function( json ) {
     jstring= JSON.parse(json);
 });
    
  console.log(jstring[0]);
```

The console log says that the object is undefined no matter what I change.

Comment: getJSON is asynchronous. The way you have it in your code the console.log call is going to run before your JSON.parse call.

Comment: @rayhatfield How do I change it so that the console.log runs after?

Answer (score 0):

You should try one of these approaches.

```
var JSONItems = []; 
$.getJSON( "js/settings.json", function( data){ 
  JSONItems = data; 
  console.log(JSONItems); 
});
```

or

```
var JSONItems = []; 
$.get( "js/settings.json", function( data){ 
  JSONItems = JSON.parse(data); 
  console.log(JSONItems); 
});
```

Comment: These still result in undefined for me.

Comment: Maybe the path to the .json file is wrong.
Try putting the console in the first line inside a function and then check the console. @BobBob